# Kubernetes - from Minikube to production

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud, minikube

I have created a simple PHP api application that works with a mysql database to store data. I have been experimenting with Kubernetes on my Windows 10 machine through Minikube.

I have just about got my head round the ideas involved, yet I’m not sure about how to implement this properly. So far I have used Kompose to create a set of yaml files from an existing docker-compose file. This has been half successful.

To get my application code into a pod hosting PHP, I have been using hostPath to share from my local machine. I mount to the minikube machine and share from there. I was having trouble sharing by other means. The application code is hosted in a github repo.

My questions are:

1. Is mounting my application code into a pod (assuming this is similar to what happens in docker) the correct way to do this? I’m not clear exactly what information is held on an image retrieved from the docker hub. Although I have read up on containers isolating the build environment from your machine.
2. How does this approach to translate into a production environment hosted on a cloud? I see there are various storage types. I had for example, wanted to try deploying on AWS just to see how this would work in practice.

I’m really looking for guidance to go from the tutorials found on the web working on my machine, to something that could be done for a customer hosted on the cloud. This might scale up to a more microservices style architecture over time.

Answer (score 3):

The approach you are describing is mostly for development setups, where you want to mount your code into the container as a volume so you don't have to rebuild every time your code changes. Typically done with a docker-compose file.

For production setups, you want the docker image to correctly work and only mount volumes to data you want to persist, typically databases are the core example. For this EKS is deeply integrated into the AWS infrastructure and will create EBS volumes on demand. You don't need to provision any volume or even care for most cases (unless you need multiple read-write volumes needed for scaling).

For a PHP application you really should not persist any data in the pod, because it will create other issues when you need to scale the application. Also, a good approach for managing files that need to persist is S3 (AWS simple storage service).

So generally speaking, you need a deployment per application a service to access each pod on that application and then an ingress object to route traffic from the internet to each pod.

Answer (score 2):

Your application docker image is really the core. You just build it with your code inside. Make sure to pass configuration using `environment` variable or configuration file so you can connect to the database.

Now for kubernetes, for each compoment (e.g. PHP application, MySQL) you will most likely create a `deployment` k8s manifest that points to the docker image and add some configuration environment variables.

For production, you will need persistence `volume`. On `aws` you can simply use `EBS`-backed `volumes`

To get traffic from Internet to your PHP application, you will need to add one or more k8s components:

1. K8s `Service` manifest that exposes your PHP deployment/pod on a stable address. If you only have q or very few services, you can use `LoadBalancer` which on cloud like AWS will create an ALB/ELB (might need to add annotation to your service)
2. An `ingress` which is just a reverse proxy (contour, nginx, traefik). On cloud environment it will map to an ALB/ELB. The advantage of this is that you can have a single ALB for all your services i.e. save money. Also you can configure routing path or TLS termination in one place.

Comment: All sounds helpful. In AWS, how do I best get the Php code into a running docker image? I’ve been reading it’s best not to embed it directly into the image using git. In my docker file, it looks like the ADD . . lines in a docker file copy these from the directory in the host. Or is this what the persistent volume is for?

Comment: The `Dockerfile` should be commited to `git` beside your code. The CI/CD server will checkout your repo which will have everything needed to buils the image. You use `COPY` in the Dockerfile to add the code to the image, then push the final image to the container registry. In a compiled langauge world e.g. Java/GO/Rust you only add to the image the final artifact not the code e.g. binary executable or jar which not possible in  your case